# MarkLogic - Constrain results by field

Tags: database, rest, xquery, marklogic

I have a MarkLogic database containing news articles in NITF format, each of which has the following information.

```
<date.issue norm="20140321T000000" news:date="2014-03-21" news:time="00:00:00" news:origin="Generated"/>
```

I am using the inbuilt REST API to access this database. I would like to constrain results by date in my query, i.e get all documents between a date range, or before or after a particular date. How is this possible with MarkLogic's REST API?

Answer (score 3):

There are three steps:

1. Build an index to support the query
2. Configure search options
3. Write the query

For #1, you'll need an xs:date range index on news:date. Range indexes allow >, ≥, =, ≤, < comparisons.

For #2, you'll need to build a constraint using the news:date index. It will look [something like this](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/appendixb#id_91924):

```
 <constraint name="news-date">
   <range type="xs:date">
     <element ns="news" name="date"/>
   </range>
 </constraint>
```

Note that the value of element/@ns needs to be the full namespace URI, not just the prefix. This constraint configuration will be part of [your REST API configuration](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_48838). (You also [have the option to use QBE instead.](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_46421))

For #3, the query will be built client side and sent to the REST API on the server. The query can be expressed as either a [query string](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/string-query#chapter) or as a [structured query](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#chapter). As a query string, you could do a between like this:

```
news-date GT 2010-01-01 AND news-date LT 2010-12-31
```

For this to work, make sure your REST API configuration includes LT, GT, and AND, which are shown in [the default query string grammar](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/string-query#id_23164).

A structured query is represented as JSON or XML. Here's the same query as JSON:

```
{
  "query": {
    "queries": [
      { 
        "and-query": {
          "queries": [
            "range-constraint-query": {
              "value": [ "2010-01-01" ],
              "constraint-name": "news-date",
              "range-operator": ">"
            },
            "range-constraint-query": {
              "value": [ "2010-12-31" ],
              "constraint-name": "news-date",
              "range-operator": "<"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave for the detailed answer. I tried out the steps, but I'm getting the following error, even though the range index is present. `XDMP-ELEMATTRRIDXNOTFOUND: cts:element-attribute-values(fn:QName("http://iptc.org/std/NITF/2006-10-18", "date.issue"), fn:QName("http://news.com", "date"), (), ("type=date", "concurrent"), cts:and-query((cts:word-query("Geert", ("lang=en"), 1), cts:word-query("Wilders", ("lang=en"), 1)), ()), xs:double("1"), ()) -- No date element-attribute range index for fn:QName("http://iptc.org/std/NITF/2006-10-18", "date.issue") fn:QName("http://news.com", "date")`

Comment: `XDMP-ELEMATTRRIDXNOTFOUND` means the range index you're trying to query does not exist. Double-check the namespaces and local names, and also check to make sure the database has finished reindexing.

Comment: Thanks. The database hadn't finished reindexing yet. Also, how exactly can I incorporate this constraint into the query string while querying with the REST API? It isn't very clear from the example given above, and the range constraint example seems to be missing from [here](http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/rest/custom-search).

Comment: My example above shows a query string using the constraint: "news-date GT 2010-01-01 AND news-date LT 2010-12-31". See [The Default String Query Grammar](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/string-query#id_23164) to see how GT, LT, and AND work. To use this, you'd send a GET request to "/v1/search?q=news-date GT 2010-01-01 AND news-date LT 2010-12-31"